# Fix MySQL high CPU usage with InnoDB

Tags: mysql, configuration, innodb, cpu, highlight

Recently my server CPU has been going very high.

Currently, My my.cnf file such as below:

```
[mysqld]
default-storage-engine=innodb
local-infile=0
skip-locking
max_connections=300
key_buffer = 128M
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 64M
join_buffer_size = 1M
read_buffer_size = 2M
sort_buffer_size = 2M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 2M
table_cache = 1024
record_buffer = 1M
thread_cache_size = 128
wait_timeout = 30
connect_timeout = 10
interactive_timeout = 10
tmp_table_size = 64M
max_heap_table_size = 64M
max_allowed_packet = 16M
max_connect_errors = 10
query_cache_limit = 1M
query_cache_size = 64M
query_cache_type = 1
[isamchk]
key_buffer=64M
sort_buffer=64M
read_buffer=16M
write_buffer=16M
[myisamchk]
key_buffer=64M
sort_buffer=64M
read_buffer=16M
write_buffer=16M
[mysqlhotcopy]
interactive-timeout
```

CPU Usage: u623.84 s78.87 cu0 cs0 - 8.12% CPU load
MYSQLD: 190%

My server information: 
Intel® Pentium® E5400 2.70GHz 2M Cache
HDD: 250GB
RAM: 4GB

Please help me!

Answer (score 1):

Set this variable (which is not in your my.cnf) to 70% of the RAM you have available:

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size=128M
```

Of course, if the CPU spikes are due to queries then you want to optimize those with indexes.